# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{1+\sqrt n}$.

Find out whether this series is absolutely convergent or conditional convergent or divergent.

Now integral test gives me that this series is not absolutely convergent and the term goes to zero so this is conditional convergent.

Am I right in this case?

Comment: Yes: that was easy, wasn't it?

Comment: @Willi Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Just to stress a point made by gimusi, to prove conditional convergence of an alternating series $\sum(-1)^na_n$ (with $a_n\gt0$ for all $n$), it's not enough to show that $a_n\to0$. You need to show that $a_n$ *decreases* to $0$.  A useful counterexample to keep in mind is

$$1-{1\over2^2}+{1\over3}-{1\over4^2}+{1\over5}-{1\over6^2}+\cdots$$

which diverges even though the terms are clearly tending to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the quote! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

In order to prove that it is not absolutely convergente, I would have used the comparison test, comparing $\frac1{1+\sqrt n}$ with $\frac1{\sqrt n}$, but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that

- for absolutely convergence consider limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{\sqrt n}$
- for conditional convergence note that $\frac1{1+\sqrt n}\to 0$ is strictly decreasing

Comment: Wow, two upvotes, two down. Opinions are split on this one! (I *really* don't see why this answer deserves a downvote, myself.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I don’t know! Thanks for the support, really appreciate! Bye

Comment: So I apparently downvoted this, and I have no clue why I did that, as it is a perfectly fine answer. My apologies. I would remove my downvote, but I cannot do so unless this is edited again.

Comment: @Tom Thanks I've edited now. But why did you downvotewithout understanding the answer? you may ask for clarification before that for the nex time also to hel me to correct in case I wuold be wrong. Thanks again. Bye

Comment: I don't quite remember my reasons, but I think I might have downvoted because I felt that it didn't offer anything new that the other answer did not contain. Looking back, this is not true and the downvote was unjustified. I have since removed it.

Comment: @Tom Thanks Tom I really appreciate your kind attention! Regards